# Sorting data from SQLite with queries or using programming language

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sqlite, sorting

I'm creating XUL app which uses SQLite database for storing data. Which is the better practice to sort and display data from DB to users - using queries such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE this=that AND...
```

or to simply get the data from DB with simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

and then sort it with whatever programming lang you are working with(in my case JavaScript). By better I'mean faster, safer and simpler?

Comment: Please use filtering and sorting in your query...  Not only does selecting everything take much longer, but the user will be seeing things they either don't want to so see, don't care to see, or should not be seeing in the first place.  In addition, it imposes a large burden on the end-user to resort to loading the entire table and sorting client-side.

Comment: it depends. if the db is slow, loading it all into ram once could be faster, and allow more customized sorting than sql provides. if the db is fast, it's often simpler to use sql to code the logic, which also uses less ram.

Answer (score 2):

Always let the database filter, sort and aggregate data! Don't do that in your programming language. Especially if you created indexes on your columns "this" or "that".